# How to select first data of same id and sum column same id sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like

```
|id|id_barang|in|out|stock|
|1|1|2|0|2|
|2|1|2|0|4|
|3|1|0|1|3|
|4|2|2|0|2|
|5|2|1|0|3|
|6|2|0|1|2|
```

I want result is group by id_barang

```
|Id_barang|sum(in)|sum(out)|first(stock)|
|1|4|1|2|
|2|3|1|2|
```

Comment: Which Database you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **MIN** function for the first stock. It works similarly to **SUM** or **COUNT**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT Id_barang, SUM(in), SUM(out), FIRST(stock)
FROM data
GROUP BY Id_barang
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `Mysql` doesn't support `Window functions`. Try this

```
SELECT b.id_barang, 
       sum_in, 
       sum_out, 
       a.stock 
FROM   yourtable A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id_barang, 
                          Sum(in)  sum_in, 
                          Sum(OUT) sum_out, 
                          Min(id)  AS min_id 
                   FROM   yourtable 
                   GROUP  BY id_barang) B 
               ON a.id_barang = b.id_barang 
                  AND a.id = b.min_id
```

Answer (score 0):

this query fetch all record of table group by Id_barang. its give first  record of stock.
`SELECT t1.Id_barang, sum(t1.in), sum(t1.out), (select min(t2.stock)
from table_name t2 where  t2.Id_barang = t1.Id_barang) 
FROM table_name t1
GROUP BY Id_barang`

Answer (score 0):

you can make query this way :

```
SELECT id_barang,SUM(in) as total_in,SUM(out) as total_out,stock
FROM stock
GROUP BY id_barang
```

if you found any error then you must change your column name, i think 'in' and 'out' is not valid. you change 'in' into 'in_change' and 'out' into 'out_change'. try with this column it works as you want. i did try....

```
SELECT id_barang,SUM(in_change) as total_in,SUM(out_change) as total_out,stock
FROM stock
GROUP BY id_barang
```